# Hard drive failed in RAID 0; can no longer boot windows

Tags: hard-drive

I have a laptop with two 500GB spinning disks, which are configured in RAID 0 (stripe). I smacked my laptop and it turned off. When I turned it back on It said one of the hard drives failed and it would not boot windows.

I wanted to make sure it was the hard drive and not the bay slot. I switched the hard drives around and it still said the same hard drive (now in a different bay) was "failed".

I am guess the failed hard drive is the one that had windows installed on it?

I never made a boot CD.
I have a CoA for windows.

My question is what do I do from here?
Do I have to turn off RAID 0? If so How do I do that?

I go to try and boot from the command it leaves me when it says one hard drive is failed, and that does not work. The laptop is a MSI GT780DXR.

Comment: Man, RAID0 is a system to boost performance that by definition makes the system more fragile.

Comment: The '0' in RAID 0 is how much data you will get back if a hard drive fails.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets explain something about RAID 0.

Read this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them

As you can read RAID 0 turns two drives or two partitions into **one** virtual disk. If one of the physical disks fails you loose access to **all** data on that RAID array.

> I am guess the failed hard drive is the one that had windows installed on it?

No. Both had (part of) the windows OS installed on them.

> Do I have to turn off RAID 0?

Changing the array configuration so that the disks are no longer in a a RAID-0 (stripe) array does not return your data. You will be left with two disks (one of which is still broken, one of which does not hold any usable data).

What you should do is:

1. Turn RAID off, using **one** single disk.
2. Reinstall windows on that single working disk.
3. Recover you data from backups.

or

1. Replace the failed disk.
2. Reinstall windows on the now working RAID array
3. Recover your data from backups.

I am assuming that you have backups for all important data since RAID-0 only gets used when you need maximum speed *at all costs*, including data safety.

Comment: Sadly the thumb drive I kept all my back ups on broke. Thank you for your answer, It really does help since I had no clue what Raid0/1 ups and downs are. For now since i cannot afford another disk, I need to turn off raid and just use 1 Disk, could you please tell me how to do this? Im assuming it is somewhere in BIOS.  Also, I do not have a windows CD, only a cd key.  Can I burn a windows start up disk on a different computer and pop it in my (currently broken one) once I turn  off the raid option?  Thank you for your time in this matter.

Comment: How to disable RAID 0 depends on how RAID 0 was enabled in the first place.  It can be enabled (and, therefore, disabled) in a BIOS on some machines.  On some machines, it is in an "option ROM" of an add-on card; you may press some keyboard input (like Ctrl-A, maybe?) during part of the bootup process, before the operating system starts to load.  Or, the RAID 0 might have been implemented in software; in that case, you may effectively disable this when you re-install the system.  There are different possibilities.  How to undo what you did (enable RAID 0) depends on how you originally did it.

Answer (score -4):

make sure your hard disk 1 is as master disk and put your 2nd disk as a slave one.
if that does not work make your 2nd hard disk as a bootable one with the new os.
then plug your 1st disk to your computer externally. There you can make backup copy of your main disk os files and your personal files also. Try it.

Comment: Master, slave and single has not been used since IDE drives. Since the poster has 500GB drives they are almost guaranteed to be SATA and this no longer applies.